# django with heavy computation and long runtime - offline computation and send results

Tags: django, rest

I have a django app where the user sends a request, and the server does some SQL lookup, followed by computation on results and finally showing the results to the user.

The SQL lookup and the computation afterwards can take a long time, maybe 30+ minutes. I have seen some webpages ask for email in such cases then send you the URL later. But I'm not sure how this can be done in django or whether there are other options for this situation. Any pointer will be very helpful.

(I'm sorry but as I said it's a rather general question, I don't know how can I provide a min runnable code for this)

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish this would be to use something like Celery, which is a distributed task queue. The processing task would go into the queue (synchronously or asynchronously), and it would call a function to send an email to the user alerting them it is ready when the task is complete.

Documentation: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html